Discrepancy in CSS Cascade Layer `!important` Behavior Between Chrome and Firefox DevTools
I'm learning about CSS cascade layers and encountered an issue with how DevTools reflect applied styles when using !important.
Here’s the setup:

I imported Bootstrap into a framework layer.
Added custom styles in a utilities layer with higher specificity using !important.
Applied the styles to an element, expecting the padding from the framework layer to take precedence based on the cascade and specificity rules.

The issue:

The actual rendered padding is correctly coming from the framework layer.
However, Chrome DevTools shows that the custom !important padding from the utilities layer is being applied.
Firefox DevTools, on the other hand, correctly reflects the applied styles as per the cascade layers.

Steps to Reproduce:

Import a CSS framework (e.g., Bootstrap) into a framework layer.
Define custom styles in a utilities layer with !important.
Apply styles to an element and inspect them in Chrome and Firefox DevTools.

Expected Result:
DevTools should correctly display the applied styles as per cascade and specificity rules.
Actual Result:
Chrome DevTools incorrectly shows that the !important styles from the utilities layer are applied, even though the framework’s styles are rendered.
Additional Info:

Chrome Version: Version 131.0.6778.205 (Official Build) (arm64)
OS: Version 15.1.1 (24B91) macOS Sequoia
Example Code: https://github.com/iheathers/css-layers

Question:
Is this a known issue with Chrome DevTools? If so, is there a workaround or setting to make it display the applied styles correctly?
Any insights or suggestions for debugging this further would be appreciated!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="p-1">Default</button>
</body>

</html>


@layer framework, utilities;

@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css") layer(framework);

@layer utilities {
    .p-1 {
        padding: 2rem !important;
    }
}





Reported the issue here for updates: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/386565137

Codepen to replicate the issue: https://codepen.io/iheathers/pen/MYgvdMY

The behaviour is the same on Windows as well. I have verified that on my other Windows laptop.
